# Where's syslinux.cfg in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: lubuntu, syslinux

Can someone tell me where the 'syslinux.cfg' file is located in Lubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Ah, well how do i make a Persistence USB stick then? The instructions tell me that i need to edit the syslinux.cfg file, so if it's not there i don't understand how i can do it? http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/diskimg/readme.txt

Comment: Please ask that as a new question, the way this site works is one post per question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no syslinux.cfg file - Ubuntu and its deriratives use GRUB as a bootloader, not syslinux. Syslinux is only used with ubuntu on installation media

Answer (score 0):

There's a `syslinux.cfg` file located in /cdrom/syslinux/.
But I'm think you are looking for remove `Try ubuntu without changes` screen and choose another language by default.
This content is present in the `txt.cfg` file on the same folder.